# Angular get property of class by name

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

Is there a way to fetch an array from a class like this below, so that I don't have to use a switch statement or a dict or some other collection to look up the name that I pass into the method?

```js
export class ProcessOptions {

  Arm = [{
      name: 'Expedited Review ("ER") (not available for Level VI, Lung Cancer 2, or Foreign Claims)',
      code: 25
    },
    {
      name: 'Individual Review ("IR")',
      code: 26
    }
  ];

  BW = [{
      name: 'Expedited Review ("ER") (not available for Level VI, Lung Cancer 2, or Foreign Claims)',
      code: 3
    },
    {
      name: 'Individual Review ("IR")',
      code: 4
    }
  ];

  GetProcessOptions(trust: string) {
    return this.Arm;
  }

}
```

Comment: Ok, well, your snippet doesn't run and your example is unclear because your ```GetProcessOptions``` is ignoring the parameter ```trust``` and returning ```this.Arm```. I'm assuming your trying to return the array designated by ```trust```. Can't you just return ```this[trust]```?

Comment: `return this[trust]` is what you are looking for

Answer (score -1):

You can do something like this:

```
export class ProcessOptions {

    Arm: [{
      name: 'Expedited Review ("ER") (not available for Level VI, Lung Cancer 2, or Foreign Claims)',
      code: 25
    },
    {
      name: 'Individual Review ("IR")',
      code: 26
    }
    ],
    BW: [{
      name: 'Expedited Review ("ER") (not available for Level VI, Lung Cancer 2, or Foreign Claims)',
      code: 3
    },
    {
      name: 'Individual Review ("IR")',
      code: 4
    }
    ]

  GetProcessOptions(trust: string) {
    return this[trust];
  }
 }
```

Comment: `container` object is not required. You will have to make additional chaining of the `properties` while accessing them elsewhere. `this[trust]` should be fine.

Comment: I don't think this works. Returns nothing. What do I pass in? A string with the name of the array? ex. "ARM"

Comment: Yes, that is what you should be passing. If you are not doing that, then what is `trust` in your case?

Comment: It's a string. Ex. "ARM"

Comment: 'Arm' and 'ARM is not the same'